# Question on ending a marriage improperly closed as a request for legal advice

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, legal-advice, close-reasons

This question [Divorce without the process of divorce; is it possible to obtain a dissolution after 15 years?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/88722/divorce-without-the-process-of-divorce-is-it-possible-to-obtain-a-dissolution-a) was closed as a request dfoer specific lewgal advice. It turns out, as the [answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/88727/17500) by user6726 makes clear, this is a matter of black-letter law, as little a question of legal advice as "can two people get married?" would be. There is such a process, there is a specific law that authorizes it, and it does not require a lawyer if then parties agree.

I call on the community, or the mods, to undo this blatantly improper closure, and reopen this question promptly. It was closed by vote. I think those who voted for closure should look at this case, and consider whether they were over hasty to VTC, and whether they ought to alter their personal standards for when to close an issue as a request for legal advice.

Answer (score 1):

## The edit and the review crossed streams

I had opened the review queue last night, before your edit, with the review for that question open in the unedited version. I had to do stuff and went to bed before I clicked anything. Then, after work I finished the queued item, still seeing the unedited version.

After the edit, it no longer looks as much like a request for legal advice as it did before.

Comment: While I think it was not an RSLA even in the original form, would you please consider voting to reopen this.

Comment: @DavidSiegel we'll see if it passes muster of 3 more.